# How to integrate CMS to existing web site

Tags: java, content-management-system, wicket

I try to solve problem with integration some CMS to existing web app.
Web app is based on java (basic 3-layered architecture). UI layer is based on
Apache Wicket framework.
Our web app is deployed on Glassfish server.

I need to put a new parts to my existing pages, it will be CMS part.

For example:
I have two divs on web page.
Whole page html is generated by wicket.
First div is generated by wicket with data from service.
Second div - CMS div is generated from csm. My idea is to ask CMS
for appropriate particional HTML for CMS element.
But it is only my idea.

Can you give me some tips how to do that, because 
i really don't know how to do it.

Thanks for your soon reply.
jason smith

Comment: This is highly dependent upon the CMS that you are working with. Does your CMS have an API or web services interface?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't chosen your CMS yet, you might want to look at the CMS projects listed in [products based on Wicket](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/products-based-on-wicket.html).